# How do I debug docker port forwarding?

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have facing an issue here, I configured a docker with a react app, everything looks good but I am not able to access on web browser, maybe anyone can help.

SO: Monterey
Docker version 20.10.9, build c2ea9bc

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
15da03cf8ae3   app-dev         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   app-dev
```

if I run

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
```

I can see the process.

I already have another container running with postgres and working.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.15.0-alpine3.15 as installer

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

ARG API_URL=http://localhost:8080


ARG UI_BASE_URL
ARG KEYCLOAK_URL

RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev:start"]
```

curl localhost:3000 returns "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

I tried run in dockerfile and compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    container_name: app-dev
    image: app-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you `docker exec` into the container, can you run `netstat -tln` or `ss -tln`? If so, what is the output? From your description, this could be a problem with your code. Have you confirmed that your code is working correctly? Can you `curl localhost:3000` and get the expected response from *inside* the container?

Comment: yes, it seems some difference between node from nvm and alpine, on docker some silent error regarding package dependency ir happening in background silently. Thanks for help!